# run C# protobuf example with errors

Tags: c#, rider, protocol-buffers

Newbie in C#, I installed Rider on MacOS and installed Google.Protobuf and protobuf-net in the solution. And I find the example of C# protobuf on [link](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/csharp/src/AddressBook), and add the files into the solution. However, when I compile the `.cs` files, I got those errors.

> Addressbook.cs(263, 57): [CS1615] Argument 1 may not be passed with the 'ref' keyword
>   Addressbook.cs(445, 61): [CS1615] Argument 1 may not be passed with the 'ref' keyword
>   Addressbook.cs(580, 57): [CS1615] Argument 1 may not be passed with the 'ref' keyword

So how to solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the methods argument do not accept a reference: `ref argument`;

To resolve this issue make sure to remove the `ref` before the arguments in the lines
263, 445, 580 of the Addressbook.cs file.

example given:

```
if (!pb::UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(ref _unknownFields, input)) {
          return;
}
```

should be:

```
if (!pb::UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(_unknownFields, input)) {
          return;
}
```

Comment: But this Addressbook.cs is created by `protoc` command, I don't think it should be modified.

Answer (score 0):

By comparing the official examples and protoc --csharp_out files, I found that the difference appears in the clause mentioned by @nnty. In the official examples, that clause is replaced by

```
_unknownFields = pb::UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(_unknownFields, input);
```

so change all the error place with above sentence may help solve the problem.